# Android: Unable to find app on devices with only front cameras

Tags: android, google-play, android-manifest, front-camera

I have an app which uses a camera for one of its functions and the camera is mandatory. 
But the app does not care whether the device has only a front camera or only back camera or both.

I am not able to see the app on devices that have only a front camera like Nexus 7 (2012) model.
I made the following change in the Manifest file but I am still not able to see the app on this device via the play store.

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="true"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.back" android:required="false"/>
```

Could someone please help me with this issue?

Comment: What is the OS version? maybe is lower than what you configure in the manifest.

Comment: no it is higher that the  min value in the Manifest

Answer (score 0):

Quoting [the documentation for `android.hardware.camera.any`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html#hw-features):

> The application uses at least one camera facing in any direction, or an external camera device if one is connected. Use this in preference to `android.hardware.camera` if a back-facing camera is not required.

There used to be a problem where the Play Store would not pay attention to that `<uses-feature>` option, but [now it does, apparently](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=35166#c16).

Comment: any idea why that could be happening

Comment: If setting it to camera.any didn't work, the problem is likely not with the camera is what my guess would be. Have you tested it on different devices? Is it only the nexus 7?

Comment: When you say you've tried it. How long did you wait before checking the play store after updating your manifest. It can take a few hours, at worst 24 hours for changes to app updates to propgogate across Google servers.